# How can I do a lot of WS calls in separate threads and increment a single result variable?

Tags: java, multithreading, struts, struts-1

Thread beginner here.

I need in a Struts action to retrieve some data by calling a webservice many times with a different request each time, and wait for every request to be completed so I can display the result.

So basically I'm doing it like this :

```
// The list of the region codes used for the requests
List<String> codesRegions;

// Init of a variable containing the total amount of data
Integer totalAmount = 0; 

// For every region
for(String codeRegion : codesRegions)
{
    MyRegionStub stub = createRegionStub();

    // Call of the WS with the code region
    MyRegionRequest request = new MyRegionRequest();
    request.setCodeRegion(codeRegion);

    // Getting the number associated to the region and incrementing totalAmount
    MyRegionResponse response = stub.getRegionStats(request);
    totalAmount += response.getRegionStats();
}

// Once all the calls are done, I display the result
request.setAttribute("totalAmount", totalAmount);
mapping.findForward("success");
```

My problem is that I often get timeout errors by doing this as I am calling this WS a lot of times. So I want to know how I can do every call in a separate thread, and increment the same result variable without any mistake.

Another thing I want to know, I need to wait for all the calls to be completed to display the data. What do I need to do to call `mapping.findForward("success");` only when this is finished?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using java 8 I would recommend [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html)

This will allow you to create a load of threads that run async something like this

```
 CompleteableFuture<Integer> future CompleteableFuture.supplyAsync(getRegionStats(codeRegion))
```

Once you have created all of the futures, you can then check when they are all completed.

```
 CompleteableFuture.allOf(future1, future2).join();
```

Then for each of your futures you can do sum the values

```
 for(CompleteableFuture future : futures)
      totalAmount+= future.get()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately, I'm working on an old project using an older version of Java (Java 6) so I can't use this solution... I'll keep it in mind for later purposes though!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Executor framework` with `CountDownLatch` for this.
`ExecutorService` will execute asynchronous tasks in thread pool and `CountDownLatch` will wait all the tasks completion.

In this case you should note that `countDownLatch.countDown();` must present in `finally` block so it is guaranteed to be executed, and for total amount you should use thread safe `AtomicInteger`.

Your code will look like this:

```
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(codesRegions.size());
AtomicInteger totalAmount = new AtomicInteger(0);

for (String codeRegion : codesRegions)
{
    threadPool.execute(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                MyRegionStub stub = createRegionStub();

                // Call of the WS with the code region
                MyRegionRequest request = new MyRegionRequest();
                request.setCodeRegion(codeRegion);

                // Getting the number associated to the region and
                // incrementing
                // totalAmount
                MyRegionResponse response = stub.getRegionStats(request);
                totalAmount.addAndGet(response.getRegionStats());
            }
            finally
            {
                countDownLatch.countDown();
            }
        }
    });
}
try
{
    countDownLatch.await();
}
catch (InterruptedException e)
{
    //Return ERROR in case of current thread is interrupted.
}
// Once all the calls are done, I display the result
request.setAttribute("totalAmount", totalAmount);
mapping.findForward("success");
```